# Why does yielding an item in a function give different output than printing the item?

Tags: python, yield

I wrote this function to read a list of words representing a number and pair 1-9 digits with multipliers.

```
def listpairs(element):
    pair = []
    for word in enumerate(element):
        pair.append(word[1])
        if word[1] in denoms:
            yield pair
            pair.clear()
        if word[1] in digits and word[0] == (len(element)-1):
            yield pair
```

When I try it with a test string, it gives this:

```
list(listpairs('two hundred three ten four'.split())
[['four'], ['four'], ['four']]
```

If I replace yield with print(pair), it gives the expected output:

```
['two', 'hundred']
['three', 'ten']
['four']
```

Why does this happen?  Is yield the wrong tool here?

Comment: Related (perhaps duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

Your are yielding the same list all the time. Replace:

```
pair.clear()
```

with:

```
pair = []
```

To get new list.

Example:

```
from string import digits
denoms = ['hundred', 'ten']

def listpairs(element):
    pair = []
    for word in enumerate(element):
        pair.append(word[1])
        if word[1] in denoms:
            yield pair
            pair.clear()
        if word[1] in digits and word[0] == (len(element)-1):
            yield pair

list(listpairs('two hundred three ten four'.split()))
```

Gives:

```
[['four'], ['four']]
```

But:

```
from string import digits

denoms = ['hundred', 'ten']

​

def listpairs(element):
    pair = []
    for word in enumerate(element):
        pair.append(word[1])
        if word[1] in denoms:
            yield pair
            pair = []
        if word[1] in digits and word[0] == (len(element)-1):
            yield pair


list(listpairs('two hundred three ten four'.split()))
```

Results int:

```
[['two', 'hundred'], ['three', 'ten']]
```

## Explanation

While `mylist.clear()` removes all content form a list, it is still the same list. Yielding the same list results in having the same list multiple times in your output.
On the other hand, the assignment `mylist = []` creates a new list, reusing the name `mylist`. Reusing the name here is fine because you yield the list, i.e. it will be outside of the function.

Comment: Thank you! I thought list.clear() was the same thing as list = []. The function works now. I still don't understand why the same object was treated differently by print and yield, though.

Comment: @cmo lists can change, doing `x = [] ; print(x) ; x.append(4) ; print(x)` will print the same list at two different times when it contains different values, if you want to be guaranteed to have immutable results then do `yield tuple(pair)` so that it creates a new `tuple` with the data at the time and then you are free to modify `pair` again as you are.